# How can I calculate total return from monthly returns

Tags: t-sql, ssms, recursive-query

I have a table like which has monthly returns as shown below.
My goal is to calculate investment growth of $10000. 
investment_growth column shown below was calculated by me manually. For the first month, 10000*(1+return/100) will be the first value. The resultant value will be substituted in the formula for the next month's return and so on.

Can someone help me with a query to achieve this.

Thank you

[monthly returns table - investment growth column is the goal]

[image]

Comment: which version of sql-server?

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: SQL Server 2016 Management Server

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a recursive CTE, which loops through your table and can reference rows that were previously calculated.  Be warned though, due to this row by row looping it can run rather slowly depending on your environment:

```
declare @t table (FundName nvarchar(5),ReturnRate decimal(5,2), EndDate date);
insert into @t values('FundA',1.2,'20171231'),('FundA',-0.7,'20180131'),('FundA',1.3,'20180228'),('FundA',-2.3,'20180331'),('FundA',2.5,'20180430'),('FundA',1.9,'20180531'),('FundA',0.8,'20180630'),('FundB',1.1,'20171231'),('FundB',-0.4,'20180131'),('FundB',1.6,'20180228'),('FundB',-1.3,'20180331'),('FundB',2.0,'20180430'),('FundB',0.9,'20180531'),('FundB',0.8,'20180630');

declare @InitialInvestment int = 10000;

with rn as        -- Apply a row number to each Fund, ordered by EndDate so the first row can be used as the anchor in the Recursive CTE below.
(
    select FundName
            ,ReturnRate
            ,EndDate
            ,row_number() over (partition by FundName order by EndDate) as rn
    from @t
)
,r as
(
    select FundName        -- Select just the first rows for each fund and calculate the Investment Growth
            ,ReturnRate
            ,EndDate
            ,rn
            ,cast(@InitialInvestment * (1 + (ReturnRate/100)) as decimal(20,10)) as InvestmentGrowth
    from rn
    where rn = 1

    union all

    select r.FundName      -- Then row by row, fetch the next and calculate the Investment Growth by referencing the previous row in the dataset
            ,rn.ReturnRate
            ,rn.EndDate
            ,rn.rn
            ,cast(r.InvestmentGrowth * (1 + (rn.ReturnRate/100)) as decimal(20,10)) as InvestmentGrowth
    from r
        join rn
            on r.FundName = rn.FundName
                and r.rn = rn.rn-1
)
select FundName
    ,ReturnRate
    ,EndDate
    ,InvestmentGrowth
from r
order by FundName
        ,EndDate;
```

Output:

```
+----------+------------+------------+------------------+
| FundName | ReturnRate |  EndDate   | InvestmentGrowth |
+----------+------------+------------+------------------+
| FundA    |       1.20 | 2017-12-31 | 10120.0000000000 |
| FundA    |      -0.70 | 2018-01-31 | 10049.1600000000 |
| FundA    |       1.30 | 2018-02-28 | 10179.7990800000 |
| FundA    |      -2.30 | 2018-03-31 |  9945.6637011600 |
| FundA    |       2.50 | 2018-04-30 | 10194.3052936890 |
| FundA    |       1.90 | 2018-05-31 | 10387.9970942691 |
| FundA    |       0.80 | 2018-06-30 | 10471.1010710233 |
| FundB    |       1.10 | 2017-12-31 | 10110.0000000000 |
| FundB    |      -0.40 | 2018-01-31 | 10069.5600000000 |
| FundB    |       1.60 | 2018-02-28 | 10230.6729600000 |
| FundB    |      -1.30 | 2018-03-31 | 10097.6742115200 |
| FundB    |       2.00 | 2018-04-30 | 10299.6276957504 |
| FundB    |       0.90 | 2018-05-31 | 10392.3243450122 |
| FundB    |       0.80 | 2018-06-30 | 10475.4629397723 |
+----------+------------+------------+------------------+
```

Comment: No worries @SunilBabuVudimudi :)  - If this was the correct solution for you question please mark it as such for the benefit of other SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Quirky Update" method

Some test data

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( [name] NVARCHAR(10), [return] DECIMAL(3,1), end_date DATE
                   , InvestmentGrowth DECIMAL(12,5) DEFAULT 0)
INSERT INTO @t
([name],[return],end_date)
VALUES
('FundA', 1.2, '20171231')
,('FundA', -0.7, '20180131')
,('FundA', 1.3, '20180228')
,('FundA', -2.3, '20180331')
```

Investment started with 10000

```
DECLARE @InvestmentAmount DECIMAL(12,5) = 10000
```

Quirky update bit

```
UPDATE @t
    SET @InvestmentAmount = InvestmentGrowth = @InvestmentAmount * (1+([T].[return]/100))
    FROM @t T;

name    return  end_date    InvestmentGrowth
FundA   1.2     2017-12-31  10120.00000
FundA   -0.7    2018-01-31  10049.16000
FundA   1.3     2018-02-28  10179.79908
FundA   -2.3    2018-03-31  9945.66370
```